# Barcode Tracker with Google Play services

Tags: android, barcode, android-bitmap

I'm implementing barcode tracking and I got everything working for the most part.

The question I have now is, is it possible to access the bitmap from where the barcode was captured? Right now, my `onUpdate()` method gets called with the correct barcode values and everything, but I'd like to also get the Bitmap of the camera frame. Anyone knows if it's possible?

Thanks!

Comment: In the googlesamples repo, there is an example for barcode reader. If you follow that, you will see a class called ui.camera.CameraSource. The barcode image can be found at onPictureTaken method.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to extract the actual bitmap from the barcode tracker, as it is only tracking barcodes and discarding whatever camera frame was analyzed to detect the barcode. However, there's a possibility to call `takePicture()` from the `onUpdate()` callback, which is how I got this working.